# Maintain order within a hash of hashes, and output as .csv

Tags: perl, csv, hash

Here's my code:

```
my %hash = (
    '2564' => {
                'st_responsible' => 'mname1',
                'critical' => '',
                'last_modified_by' => 'teamname1',
                'transstatus' => '',
                'rt_res' => 'pname1'
                },
    '2487' => {
                'st_responsible' => 'mname2',
                'critical' => '',
                'last_modified_by' => 'teamname2',
                'transstatus' => '',
                'rt_res' => ''
                }
);

print "xnum,st_responsible,critical,last_modified_by,transstatus,rt_res\n";
foreach my $x_number (sort keys %hash)
{
    print "$x_number";
    foreach my $element (keys %{$hash{$x_number}})
    {
        print ",$hash{$x_number}{$element}";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

**Expected output**

```
xnum,st_responsible,critical,last_modified_by,transstatus,rt_res
2487,mname2,,teamname2,,
2564,mname1,,teamname1,,pname1
```

**Actual output**

```
xnum,st_responsible,critical,last_modified_by,transstatus,rt_res
2487,mname2,,,teamname2,
2564,mname1,,,teamname1,pname1
```

Please help in letting me know as to how exactly do I preserve the order of this data structure, and then write this to a `CSV` file.

Comment: NULL values may not be printed/kept. Try putting a space instead (' ').

Comment: I am getting the following with the '' stuff. xnum,st_responsible,critical,last_modified_by,transstatus,rt_res
2487,,,teamname,,mname
2564,pname,,teamname,,mname. (This probably shows up squashed.)

Comment: This is what I get if I put a space between the single quotes:xnum,st_responsible,critical,last_modified_by,transstatus,rt_res
2487,mname,teamname, , ,
2564,pname,teamname, , ,mname.

Comment: @MarkManning: The problem being faced here is the preservation of the hash in the exact order of appearance. It's alright if there's no white-space/NULL being inserted at this point of time.

Comment: @Ghost : Yeah, Jbynek's answer showed me where I was wrong. I used to be a really big Perl person - now I'm more PHP. But having to relearn since I'm looking at a Perl job now.

Comment: @MarkManning: Wish you the best of luck in your endeavors. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that for this, you'd be better off doing this with a [`slice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices), which is a way of extracting a list of values from a hash in a particular order?

```
#configure field order
my @order = qw ( st_responsible critical last_modified_by transstatus rt_res );

#print header row 
print join (",", "xnum", @order ),"\n"; 
#iterate the rows
foreach my $key ( sort keys %hash ) { 
   #extract hash slice and join it with commas
   print join ( ",", $key, @{$hash{$key}}{@order} ),"\n";
}
```

This gives:

```
xnum,st_responsible,critical,last_modified_by,transstatus,rt_res
2487,mname2,,teamname2,,
2564,mname1,,teamname1,,pname1
```

You can consider `Text::CSV` - but I'd suggest in this scenario it's overkill, best used when you've got quotes and quoted field separators to worry about. (And you don't).

If you have to deal with not just empty keys, but missing ones, you can make use of `map`:

```
my @order = qw ( st_responsible critical last_modified_by 
                 transstatus missing rt_res extra_field_here );
print join (",", "xnum", @order ),"\n"; 
foreach my $key ( sort keys %hash ) { 
   print join ( ",", $key, map { $_ // '' } @{$hash{$key}}{@order} ),"\n";
}
```

(Otherwise you'll get a warning about an undef value).

Comment: It works. Thank you very much for providing solution

Comment: When values contains ',' or any special characters out put of csv is not proper. for example
st_responsible' => 'mn, ame/2',

Comment: Yes. But your original code has that problem too. To handle that case, using Text::CSV is the tool for the job

Answer (score 1):

Perl doesn't guarantee the order of items in the hash, this is the root cause of the issue. Even two different hashes with the same keys can have different order of keys. It may also differ from platform to platform and architecture and perl version.

You need to define another array with the list of keys which you want to print in correct order.

```
my @keys = qw(st_responsible critical last_modified_by transstatus rt_res);
foreach my $element (@keys) {
    ... print the value
}
```

EDIT: As you're trying to write CSV file, consider using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.33/lib/Text/CSV.pm) which takes care about special characters, correct formatting and things like that.

Comment: Did you notice that both what he is getting and what he wants is the 2487 and then 2564?  Also, did you notice that by putting in a single space into the '' values returns exactly what he said he wanted?

Comment: @MarkManning: No, it doesn't.  I'm talking about the values in the inner hashes, not the outside and here the issue is completely different. Note the `,,,` instead of `,,` and the opposite at the end of the row. Please read the explanation again.

Comment: ZbynekVyskovsky - I read your explanation and understand it but....well, now the original posting is different so what I saw I thought I was getting.  Now I can see that I am not getting the same.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a slicker way of achieving this, but give this a go:

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

open my $csv_out, '>', 'out.csv' or die $!;

my @keys = qw(2487 2564);
my @vals = qw(st_responsible critical last_modified_by transstatus rt_res);


print $csv_out "xnum,st_responsible,critical,last_modified_by,transstatus,rt_res\n";

for my $key (@keys){
    print $csv_out "$key,";
        for my $vals (@vals){
            $vals eq $vals[-1] ? print $csv_out "$hash{$key}{$vals}\n" : print $csv_out "$hash{$key}{$vals},";
        }
}
```

This will print out comma-separated values to a csv file `out.csv` maintaining your original order (by iterating over arrays). If it's the last value it will print a newline.

--- OUTPUT ---

```
xnum,st_responsible,critical,last_modified_by,transstatus,rt_res
2487,mname2,,teamname2,,
2564,mname1,,teamname1,,pname1
```